# How to avoid maximum Workgroup Manager connections in Mac OS X Server 10.6

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, openldap

Is there a limit on the Mac OS X Server (10.6) Workgroup Manager in respect to concurrent connections to a server?

I have an OS X server up and running and Open Directory configured but I am not able to log in remotely as I get the message the maximum number of connections for Workgroup Manager is already reached and I should wait for a user to disconnect. Even after a restart I get this message remotely.

However, locally on the server I can start Workgroup Manager without any issues. It always lets me connect. Any advice what I need to do to make Workgroup Manager work from a remote location? I could not find any max connection setting in Server-Admin and nothing in the slapd log files.

The server license says unlimited so I am quite sure it should not be a regular error message that indicates to me I should upgrade.

Comment: Is it possible that you have restricted (some of) the relevant ports in the firewall?

Comment: I have ports 625 and 626 open. Even with the firewall turned off completely I got the message I should wait for another user to disconnect before I could log in using Workgroup Manager.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a rare case here, but not so uncommon that Apple's Discussion area wouldn't know about it. I am using 10.7 on my admin MacBook and apparently using Workgroup Manager 10.7 with Mac OS X Server 10.6 is not working as of this writing. Maybe an update fixes this so I can use the same MacBook to admin our 10.6 and 10.7 servers.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/15772562